# Android Fill Text String from SQLite Database

Tags: android, arrays, string, sqlite

I use a string to populate a textview on an listview

```
String[] text1 = { "Afghanistan", "Algeria" ,"Fred"};
```

I want to replace the 3 strings in the string array with data from a database. I have tried the following

```
    String text1[];
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAsset3();
    int counter = 0;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {

        text1[counter]=c.getString(0);

    counter++;  
    }
```

getAsset3 from DBAdapter

```
public Cursor getAsset3() throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, "SURVDAT", new String[] {KEY_SR1,KEY_SR2,KEY_SR3,KEY_SR4,KEY_SR5,KEY_SR6,KEY_SR7}, null, null,null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        //mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

When I run the app crashes saying Null PointerException

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Any help Appreciated

Mark

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception? NPEs are most likely caused by not initializing a variable properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize `text1` in your second snippet, so when you type `text1[counter] = c.getString(0);` you are trying to get `counter`'th index of `null`

You shall do something like

```java
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAsset3();
String text1[] = new String[c.getCount()];
for(int i = 0; cursor.moveToNext(); ++i)
{
    text1[i] = c.getString(0);
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I get the error "Type Mismatch:Cannot covert string to string" on the line  String text1[] = new String(c.getCount());

Comment: Thanks Again I worked it out needed to change line to String[] text1 = new String[c.getCount()]; and it works

Comment: @MarkBarr yes, my typo.